# Symbol 001E in a box on a Linux terminal

Tags: linux, sed, special-characters

When reading a Windows log file in a Linux terminal, I see a strange symbol “001E”

[image]

How can I replace it by space? Maybe something like `sed -e 's/010e/ /'`

Comment: What encoding does your terminal use?

Answer (score 1):

If you see these four hexadecimal digits in a box, it means your terminal's font does not cover that character. The hexadecimal notation tells you which character it is: U+001E, which is in the [control character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) range — 1E is `^^` (i.e. `Ctrl-^`).

If you want to replace it with a space, you can use

```
sed -e 's/\x1E/ /g' <input-file >output-file
```

or

```
tr '\036' <input-file >output-file
```

(`tr` only accepts octal).

Answer (score 0):

To replace [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D WITH CARON](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/010E/index.htm), do this:

```
$ sed 's/Ď/ /g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8562661/15165) answer as a reference:

```
CHARS=$(python -c 'print u"\u001E".encode("utf8")')
sed 's/['"$CHARS"']//g' < /tmp/utf8_input.txt > /tmp/ascii_output.txt
```

I am not sure what is your character though... The screenshot suggests it is 0x001e but you have mentioned 0x010e. Whichever it is, you can just change the script above as needed.